# How to verify whether a link read from file is present on webpage or not?

Tags: file-io, hyperlink, click, selenium-webdriver

I am new at automation. I have to write a code as follow

I have to read around 10 url's from a file and store it into one hashtable then I need to read one by one url's from hashtable and while iterating through this url I also need to read one more file conataining 3 url's and search them on webpage . If present need to click that link

I have written following code but I am not getting the logic for checking whether a link from file is present on webpage or not...
Please check my code and help me to solve/improve it.

```
Main test script 
package com.samaritan.automation;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstScript {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();     
    String data;
    CommonControllers commonControll = null;
    Hashtable<String, String> recruiters = null;


    @Test
    public void script() throws Exception {  
        CommonControllers commonControll = new CommonControllers();
        recruiters = new Hashtable<String,String>();

        recruiters = commonControll.readDataFromFile("D:/eRecruiters/_Recruiters.properties");

        Set<String> keys = recruiters.keySet();

        for(String key: keys){

        /**HERE I NEED TO WRITE THE FUNCTION TO VERIFY WHETHER THE LINK READ FROM SECOND FILE IS PRESENT ON WEBPAGE OR NOT**/
        }
   }    

}
```

and function to read from file into hashtable

```
public Hashtable<String, String> readDataFromFile(String fileName) {
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String strLine = null;
                String []prop = null;
                while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    prop = strLine.split("\t");
                    recruiters.put(prop[0], prop[1]);
                }
                br.close();
                fr.close();

            }catch(Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Unable to read data from recruiter file: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
            return recruiters;
        }
```

PLease take a look! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Priya...You can use

```
 if(isElementPresent(By.linkText(LinkTextFoundFromFile))){
      //code when link text present there
 }else {
      //code for not finding the link
 }
```

Now the following method is generalized for any `By` object you can use like `By.xpath`, `By.id` etc.

```
 private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
     try {
       driver.findElement(by);
       return true;
     } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       return false;
     }
   }
```

Comment: But how to get each element from hashtable at a time? I mean retrieve url (value appeneded by key) from hashtable. Could you tell me solution for that